# react-bootstrap row fill all available space

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need stretch row to the start of footer. Bootstrap has class `h-100`, but it doesn't work in my case and I don't know why.
I'm new in frontend, but I all examples on the internet didn't help me(

```
<div className="App">
  <header>
    <h1>App</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <Container fluid>
      <Row className="h-100">
        <Col xs={2} className="ml-0 bg-secondary">
          <Sidebar />
        </Col>
        <Col className="p-1 p-md-4">
          <AnotherComponent />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>
      Footer text
    </p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Result: 
[image: result]

Upd: after adding `vh-100` class to the Container
[image: Upd]

Upd: make position relative
Main screen: 
[image: main]
After scrolling:
[image: scroll]

Comment: what you want to achieve ????

Comment: did you tried giving 100% height to sidebar ??

Comment: @AkhilAravind yes, I tried. As I understand, 100% height equals the height of col where sidebar is placed, but bootstrap sets the height of cols by it's own

Comment: @PrakashKarena I want to stretch Row's content height to the start of the footer

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg did you tried 100vh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to give full view height to your container directly

```
 <Container className="vh-100 d-flex flex-column "> 
       <Row className="h-100">
  ......
```

Comment: add display flex and let me know what happne

Comment: Ok, sidebar stretched to the end of the page, but there is collision with footer now(

Comment: The height of the sidebar returns to the first example if I remove `h-100` class for the Row

Comment: your sidebar is always open like above or you are making it toggle ??

Comment: It's always open

Comment: you want to show your footer in full width .right ??

Comment: Yes, it is. Footer styles are: position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%;

Comment: oho problem is with  position: absolute;  make it as relative

Comment: Ok, it works. But now I have to scroll to see footer although there is no so many contents

Comment: play with https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_template1   here you can check how bootstrap works or not

Comment: I mean, when I set `position: relative;` for the footer, it's gone down to the end of the page, and I have to scroll to see it (see the new upd it the post)

Comment: remove vh it will tack full view port height

Comment: Yes, the footer should be sticky

Comment: Thank you very much! And sorry for my mistakes)

Comment: it's ok you need to more focus on basics of bootstrap.keep learning :)

Comment: Adding my 2 pennies: this is a nice solution for ReactJS applications whose root component DOES NOT fill the entire screen. Just add Bootstrap's `vh-100` class to the root component.

Answer (score 0):

class `h-100` will take parent height, so here Row will take container height which is row height needed to show its children.
what you need to do is calculate  the height of the remaining space:

```
container Height = (fullpage height) -(footer height + header height)
```

code with react [here](https://codepen.io/iziz96/pen/zYxMwWP)

```
  componentDidMount(){
    const header = document.querySelector("header").offsetHeight  
    const footer = document.querySelector("footer").offsetHeight
     document.querySelector(".my-container").style.height =`${window.innerHeight-(header+footer)}px`
  }
```

this the main code placed componentDidMount or useEffect if you are using functional component

Comment: Looks like what I need, but I can't understand where I should place these code to see a result